# Eigenvectors of a large sparse matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scipy, arpack

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the first few eigenvectors of a very large sparse matrix in tensorflow, hoping that it might be faster than scipy's implementation of ARPACK, which doesn't seem to support parallel computing. At least, as far as I noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should rather look into [PETCs4py](https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py) or [SLEPc4py](https://bitbucket.org/slepc/slepc4py). 
They are python binding of PETSc (Portable, Extensible Toolkit for
Scientific Computation) and SLEPc (Scalable Library for Eigenvalue Problem Computations).

PETSc and SLEPc support MPI and therefore PETCs4py and SLEPc4py do too.

I believe you will find useful examples in [examples](http://slepc.upv.es/slepc4py-current/docs/usrman/tutorial.html#commented-source-of-a-simple-example)

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed performance-wise, it's already an improvement even before figuring out how to use it with parallel computing.